# React server (front-end) is blocking express server (back-end)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-applications, frontend, backend

Here is my **package.json** file

```
{

      "name": "crypto",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --watchAll",
        "start": "npm run build-client && node index.js",
        "dev": "npm run dev-client & npm run start-redis && cross-env ENV='development' nodemon index.js",
        "dev-peer": "cross-env GENERATE_PEER_PORT='true' ENV='development' nodemon index.js",
        "start-redis": "redis-server --daemonize yes",
        "build-client": "npm run clean && parcel build client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist",
        "dev-client": "npm run clean && parcel client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist",
        "clean": "rm -rf .cache client/dist"
      },
      "jest": {
        "testEnvironment": "node"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
        "jest": "^26.0.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "elliptic": "^6.5.3",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "hex-to-binary": "^1.0.1",
        "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
        "pubnub": "^4.28.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "redis": "^3.0.2",
        "request": "^2.88.2",
        "uuid": "^3.3.2"
      },
      "description": ""
    }
```

When i run command `npm run dev`, i receive following **Result**,

$ npm run dev

> crypto@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Education Use\crypto
> npm run dev-client & npm run start-redis && cross-env ENV='development' nodemon index.js

> crypto@1.0.0 dev-client C:\Users\Education Use\crypto
> npm run clean && parcel client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist

> crypto@1.0.0 clean C:\Users\Education Use\crypto
> rm -rf .cache client/dist

Server running at http://localhost:1234
✨  Built in 107.61s.

that is only **running dev-client** and **blocking epress server**.
Guide me please...

Comment: You should run two commands one for the front react (it runs react server) and the second one the express server. `npm run start_front_dev` (for the react) and `npm run dev` for the back. Your issue is here because the process of react server won't finish

Comment: @BENARDPatrick I am following an online course and instructor's Both servers are running with single `npm run dev` command, but for my case it is not working.